# Wordpress serving my local classe C adress instead of my domain name

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ssl, raspberry-pi

i've already seen some people have the same problem as me, but the answer seem to not working for my case

I've already try to update the wp_option table in the database

My config is Lemp
raspbian nginx maria db and php-fpm.

When elsewhere, people can acccess my website, therefore no possibility to get to wp-admin

When i'm at home, the website try to connect to my local 192.168.0.17 adress

Thanks a lot if you have at least some clues

(ps : i haven't achieved yet to copy the code i'm looking forward to that)

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
 root /var/www/html/wordpress;
 index index.php;
 server_name 89.159.145.136 rockenconcept.fr;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/rnc.access_log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/rnc.error_log
 notice;
 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }
 location ~ \.php$
 {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 }

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/rockenconcept.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/rockenconcept.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = rockenconcept.fr) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


 listen 80;
 server_name 89.159.145.136 rockenconcept.fr;
return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

ok it semms to work, at least i've learned one thing today